# Problem with Timeit - Processing time - Weird Number

Tags: python-3.x, timeit

Basicly i have a file who have the code to  calculate the time of some process. But it`s not working right. Just work if i put the contents of functions inside my main.

Wrong calculate from file util.py

```py
import timeit

start_process = 0
finish_process = 0

def starting_process():
    start_process = timeit.default_timer()

def time_process():
    finish_process = timeit.default_timer()
    time_total = finish_process - start_process

    # output running time in a nice format.
    mins, secs = divmod(time_total, 60)
    hours, mins = divmod(mins, 60)

    return "Total running time: %d:%d:%d" % (hours, mins, secs)
```

In a process who spend 4 seconds, it show me like this: **238:23:55**

If i put this code in my main without functions it shows right: **0:0:4**

Anyone can help in why it is happening?

Thanks,

Lucas Antoni.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This function:

```
def starting_process():
    start_process = timeit.default_timer()
```

creates a *local variable* `start_process`, sets a value, then returns `None` (since there is no explicit return statement). The value is lost when the function ends. The function does not affect the global variable `start_process`.

So when `time_process()` is called, the expression which uses `start_process` sees that there is no local variable of that name in `time_process`, but instead finds the global variable which is set to 0.

One way to fix this would be to use

```
def starting_process():
    global start_process
    start_process = timeit.default_timer()
```

to tell `starting_process` that the variable `start_process` is the global variable.